# Python Module not Found from `systemd` service Script

Tags: python, bash, systemd

With the dozens of previous answers, I'm surprised I couldn't find anything...

I'm using the `paho` mqtt library for a very simply python program to report out some data (running on a Raspberry Pi).  My import from within the python program (my_program.py) is:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
```

If I run the program from the command line using `python my_program.py` it runs without error. However, I'm trying to get it setup as a system service to manage its execution.  I've done this a dozen times with similar python programs, setting up the various bash scripts and service files.  They all work except this one.  I mention this because I don't think it is related to the bash or the service per se.  For completeness, here is the setup.

From a bash script/systemd that runs -

```
## Service (my_program.service):
ExecStart=/home/pi/my_program.sh

## and bash (my_program.sh)
python /home/pi/my/directory/my_program.py
```

When I go to start the service, I get:

```
pi@ArmstrongSE:/etc/systemd/system $ sudo systemctl status my_program
* my_program.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/my_program.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-11-23 13:59:58 PST; 22s ago
  Process: 31100 ExecStart=/home/pi/my_program.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 31100 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 23 13:59:54 ArmstrongSE systemd[1]: Started my_program.service.
Nov 23 13:59:54 ArmstrongSE my_program.sh[31100]: Starting MQTT Transmitter
Nov 23 13:59:55 ArmstrongSE my_program.sh[31100]: /home/pi/data/solar/20191123135605.json
Nov 23 13:59:58 ArmstrongSE my_program.sh[31100]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Nov 23 13:59:58 ArmstrongSE my_program.sh[31100]:   File "/home/pi/my/directory/my_program.py", line 25, in <module>
Nov 23 13:59:58 ArmstrongSE my_program.sh[31100]:     import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
Nov 23 13:59:58 ArmstrongSE my_program.sh[31100]: ImportError: No module named paho.mqtt.client
```

To confirm that the path assignments are there - -

From the python interpreter I get:

```
>>> import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
>>> print(mqtt.__file__)
/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.pyc
```

The `sys.path` reports:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
'/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0']
```

I'm stuck...  Any thoughts on why this won't load?

**Update/Clarification:**

I can run the bash script from anywhere (any directory) and it works.  So, it must be something in the `systemd` setup (?).

Comment: "from the python interpreter I get".  You did that as root...?

Comment: No, that was done as pi (the only user on the system); to be clear it wasn't done with `sudo` either.  I think it has something to do with the system file - it runs fine as pi, but not when started in systemd.  It's not lost on me that I have everything installed locally under user pi - but I'm also running everything as user pi. (?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I figured out what the issue is...  `systemd` runs its services by default as `root`.  Which would/should, I would think (see below), allow for the equivalent of running things as `root` using sudo for another user or the actual `root` user on the cli.

Just focusing on the services file for the systemd, I found in the [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.exec.5.html) that there is a `[Service]` parameter that allows you to designate who runs the service.  In this case, I tried setting the parameter as:

```
[Service]
User=pi
ExecStart=/home/pi/my_program.sh
```

This allowed the service to run without the error (the error noted above).

I can also use these settings and execute without error:

```
[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=/home/pi/my_program.sh
```

**Why:**

For others who find themselves here, if you omit the `User=` parameter from the `[Service]` section the default is `root`.  HOWEVER, that is different than setting the `User=` parameter to `root` (e.g., `User=root`) or to another user (in my case pi).

I don't really understand the nuances, but from the documentation on [environmental variables](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment%20variables%20in%20spawned%20processes), the `User=` parameter is used to set the `$PATH` variable.  if the service file doesn't have a `User=` set I think it causes a problem with the path assignments.  I think that's why setting `User=` to either pi or root solves this problem, while using the default seems to cause the problem.

Explanations and education welcome.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a linking issue that python has. If you were to install a library via pip, it may or may not link or install properly. I would suggest re-installing the mqtt library using something like...

```
sudo -H pip3 install --system paho-mqtt
```

Also, I noticed that your import is wrong. You wrote: `import pho.mqtt.client as mqtt`.

It should be :

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
```

Comment: The -H parameter worked. I left off the --system. I did this for paho-mqtt and pubnub.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install module with root.